# Adding a resource to an app with Appgyver and Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am new to creating apps, and I'm trying to create an app with Appgyver. I want to add a simple database backend to store data. I created an account with Parse, and I uploaded my database there. On the Appgyver side I added Parse as my provider, and I added the app key and my REST key. When I go to add a resource it ask for a class UID.

What is the class UID and how do I know what it is for my database on Parse?

Answer (score 0):

Class UID is the name you gave to your resource.

[image: screenshot from Parse Data Browser]

In the above example the UID is **"TestObject"**